# Reading a JSON file in Ruby prepending unknown characters

Tags: ruby

I have a simple JSON file like this:

```
{ 
  "env": "Development", 
  "app_host": "https://localhost:3455", 
  "server_host": "localhost", 
  "server_port": "3455" 
}
```

When I read this file using the below code, the output contains some unknown characters in the beginning.

```
contents = IO.read('config.json') 
puts contents 


output: 

∩╗┐{ 
  "env": "Development", 
  "app_host": "https://localhost:3455", 
  "server_host": "localhost", 
  "server_port": "3455" 
}
```

Can someone let me know how to fix this?

Comment: Issue cannot be recreated. Make sure there is no hidden character preceding `{` in first line of the file

Comment: I just figured the issue. There are no special characters in the beginning of json file, but editing the file in Visual studio causing this issue.

Thanks Shivam.

Answer (score 4):

These characters are the bytes of a [UTF-8 byte order mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8), being displayed as [code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) characters.

From your comment, it seems Visual Studio is inserting a BOM into the files. When you then read the file in and try to display it in your console it is displaying as `∩╗┐`, since your console’s encoding is set to CP437, and the three bytes that make up the BOM in UTF-8 (`0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`) correspond to those characters in that encoding.

You should probably look into changing the encoding your console is using, as well as seeing if you can configure VS not to add the BOM (I’m not on Windows so I don’t know how you would do either of those).

From the Ruby side, you could specify the encoding in your call to `IO.read` like this:

```
IO.read('config.json', :encoding => 'bom|utf-8')
```

This will strip the BOM when reading the file.